# Spring Data JPA No qualifying bean of type ... found for dependency

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, autowired

I have sample test program to test Spring Data JPA, but it seems like the repository doesn't get generated.

My config:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd">

    <import resource="securityConfig.xml" />

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.test">
        <context:exclude-filter type="annotation"
                expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />
    </context:component-scan>

    <jee:jndi-lookup id="myDataSource" jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/test"/>

    <bean id="myEmf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.test.security" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="myEmf" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

User entity:

```
package com.test.security;

import org.springframework.security.core.CredentialsContainer;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

@Entity
@Table
public class UserPrincipal implements UserDetails, CredentialsContainer, Cloneable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private long id;
....
}
```

UserRespository:

```
package com.test.security;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<UserPrincipal, Long>
{
    UserPrincipal getByUsername(String username);
}
```

UserService:

```
package com.test.security;

@Service
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {
    @Inject
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public UserPrincipal loadUserByUsername(String username) {
        UserPrincipal principal = userRepository.getByUsername(username);
        // make sure the authorities and password are loaded
        principal.getAuthorities().size();
        principal.getPassword();
        return principal;
    }
}
```

I get this error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains':
>   Cannot resolve reference to bean
>   'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0' while
>   setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [0]; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0':
>   Cannot resolve reference to bean
>   'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0'
>   while setting constructor argument with key [3]; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0':
>   Cannot resolve reference to bean
>   'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0' while
>   setting bean property 'authenticationManager'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0':
>   Cannot resolve reference to bean
>   'org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0'
>   while setting constructor argument; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0':
>   FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager': Cannot resolve
>   reference to bean
>   'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0'
>   while setting constructor argument with key [0]; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0':
>   Cannot resolve reference to bean 'userService' while setting bean
>   property 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'userService': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: com.test.security.UserRepository
>   com.test.security.UserService.userRepository; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type [com.test.security.UserRepository] found for
>   dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@javax.inject.Inject()}

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> No qualifying bean of type [com.test.security.UserRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}

Grab the spring data jpa namespace (from spring-data-jpa jar)

```xml
xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
xsi:schemaLocation=
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
```

And use the `<repositories>` element of the jpa namespace to scan for repositories

```xml
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.test.security"
                  entity-manager-factory-ref="myEmf"
                  transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager"/>
```

See more at [Creating Repository Instances](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.create-instances)

Here's a snippet stated about the `<repositories>` tag:

> Spring is instructed to scan [`com.test.security`] and all its subpackages for interfaces extending `Repository` or one of its subinterfaces. For each interface found, the infrastructure registers the persistence technology-specific `FactoryBean` to create the appropriate proxies that handle invocations of the query methods

Here's the link for the [namespace info](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html)

For Java config, you could achieve the same thing with the `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation. You can read more about that in the same [link as above](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html)

Comment: Isn't <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.test.security" /> suppose to search for the interfaces for repositories?

Comment: No that scans for entities for the entity manager faactory. That has nothing to do with Spring beans/components